# How can I call a python's local function from an HTML doc?

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, web

I have written a python file with several functions. Now I'm writting a web page where I want to call a function of the file that I mentioned before, by pressing a button but I don't know how.

Can someone help me, or telling me where can I look for some example where python and html are connected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to set up a server to handle HTTP requests.

Then, something that can interpret python codes is needed. [`mod_wsgi`](https://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/) is a good choice for python. But for a simpler way, you can also use CGI (take a look [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_cgi_programming.htm)).

#### Edit:

A more complete/structured solution is using a python web framework. For instance, [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) or [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/). But be prepared to spend more time on them.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to talk only about a front end solution , well known solution for back end only exist (Django) and the others will certainly talk about it.

Beforehand, you should know that using Python as a front end web language is very strange. 
The "King" of these languages is JavaScript, and if you want to go further with web development, especially with front end frameworks (AngularJS, react), you should probably learn it.

That being said, [there is a way](http://www.brython.info/) to achieve what you want.

Either with this Python framework, or with a [transpiler](https://github.com/PythonJS/PythonJS).